# Error showing json_encode alert with phpmailer

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, post, phpmailer

I have one function post in my jquery file, that insert data into database and send one mail. That work fine without the phpmailer, showing alert, but when i put the phpmailer code alert dont work(but insert into database and send email), someone knows why this happen, and sory for bad english, thx for the help.

Update: I already get the alert changing json_encode to return on webservice and changing the alert(response); to return alert(response); on post code, but need to put an alert after close the post method, if dont do that the return alert dont appers, some idea why need that second alert after method post to get the return, thx.

My post code

```
$.post('insert',{val: message,name: $("#firstName").val(),desktop_id: $("#desktop_id").val(),permis: $("#permis").val(),phone: $("#phone").val(),mail: $("#mail").val()}, function (response) {
    //feedback
    alert(response);
});
```

My webservice

```
$app->post('/insert', function(){
require_once('db/dbconnect.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$phone=(int)$phone;
$mail =$_POST['mail'];
$desktop_id = $_POST['desktop_id'];
$desktop_id=(int)$desktop_id;
$permis=$_POST['permis'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$data=array("name"=>$name,"phone"=>$phone,"mail"=>$mail,"desktop_id"=>$desktop_id,"permis"=>$permis,"date"=>$date);
$client=$db->client();
$result = $client->insert($data);
if($result){
$response = 'Success';
}
else{
$response = 'Error';
}
//I remove the variables data
include_once("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$To = $destinatarios;
$Subject = $assunto;
$Message = $value;
$Host = 'mail.'.substr(strstr($usuario, '@'), 1);
$Username = $usuario;
$Password = $senha;
$Port = "587";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$body = $Message;

$mail-> IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

$mail-> Host = $Host; // SMTP server

$mail-> SMTPDebug = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only

$mail-> SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication

$mail-> Port = $Port; // set the SMTP port for the service   server

$mail->addAttachment('mpdf/temp/doc.pdf');

$mail-> Username = $Username; // account username 

$mail-> Password = $Password; // account password

$mail-> SetFrom($usuario, $nomeDestinatario);
$mail-> Subject = $Subject;
$mail-> MsgHTML($body);
$mail-> AddAddress($To, "");
if(!$mail-> Send())
{
}
else 
{
}
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
});
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the email its send succeful, but the alert dont work no more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `$response = 'Error: '. print($mail->ErrorInfo);` or `$response = 'Success'`, and then `echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`, you look like you are trying to turn an improperly formatted string into JSON.

Comment: Also, `print` outputs to the browser, it doesn't return a string. I suspect you want the `.` concatenation operator, plus format it as valid JSON.

Comment: ok i just remove that part of the phpmailer for not confuse, the alert of the if with the var $response dont work no more when put the phpmailer, sory for bad english

Comment: Use something like `$response = array('Message' => 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo)` for errors and `$response = array('Message' => 'Success')`

Comment: i gonna try that tomorow thx, but why without the code of phpmailer there work, its strange, thx

Comment: It works without the calls to `json_encode()` because what you are trying to encode cannot be turned into a valid json string.

Comment: thx already update the quest, you give me the idea to use return instead